# Hide a document from the searching in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We want to use Elasticsearch as primary data source, and we also want to keep track of changes of document, so we want to store all the versions of a document.

As a solution will be to hide previous document versions from the index, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch has `_version` field, which is increased if you make a update to the same document, while query you can specify to get the highest version of a document to get the latest document.

More information on how to do is in [elasticsearch version support blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support)

Edit:- Question asked in comment is that can we get a particular version document and answer is yes, also mentioned in official doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html and you can get it using query param but it has to be the current version otherwise you will get `version_conflict_engine_exception`, sample request looks like

> http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/{{index-name}}/_doc/2?version={your doc
>   version}

Comment: Is it possible to extract the entire document for some version? For example the last version is 5, and I need to retrieve the version 2

Comment: @user13674325 sorry for the delay in response missed your last comment and then got busy, yes you can using the query param but it has to be the current version otherwise you will get version conflict exception, adding more info in answer.

Comment: @user13674325 btw you can again comment  to remind me so that I get the notification again and work on it